# Multiprocessing a for loop with cv2 in python

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

This is my code:

```
def calculation_multi():
    print("multi")
    start = time.time()
    for y in range(image.shape[0]):
        for x in range(image.shape[1]):
            for c in range(image.shape[2]):
                new_image[y,x,c] = np.clip(kontrast*image[y,x,c] + jasnosc, 0, 255)
    end = time.time()
    print((end-start), "z multiprocessing na",multiprocessing.cpu_count(),"rdzenie")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    calculation_multi()
    calculation()
    cv.imshow('Oryginal', image)
    cv.imshow('Nowy obraz', new_image)
    cv.waitKey()
```

I want to make `calculation_multi` as multiprocessing to compare speed. How can I make it? I spent a lot of time making it but no sucess.

Comment: The best multi processing you can achieve is the numpy implementation: 

`new_image = np.clip(kontrast * image + jasnosc, 0, 255)`
. Your `calculation_multi` funcntion is purely sequential, and single-threaded.

Comment: I want to use it with multiprocessing. Is it possible to achieve it?

Comment: I'm not good at multi-processing. You can try with Pool.map() as in https://superfastpython.com/multiprocessing-pool-map/.

Comment: Numpy is roughly a thousand times faster than a pure-Python implementation. You can certainly write a multiprocessing version of the above loop, but it will not beat doing it in numpy unless you have a thousand cores.

Comment: multiprocessing requires that you have separate function calls that each do a piece of the work.

Comment: how can i make this function and call each of them?